# Undefined function 'normalize' for input arguments of type 'double'

Tags: matlab, undefined, normalization

I want to use the MATLAB function "`normalize`" which normalizes the data to zero mean and unit variance. During the compilation, I still get the error:

> Undefined function '`normalize`' for input arguments of type '`double`'.

Although this function support double inputs.

When I typed:

```
which normalize -all
```

I got:

> ```
> C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017a\toolbox\signal\signal\@dfilt\normalize.m  % dfilt method
> ```

Could any one help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You're likely using a version of MATLAB older than R2018a, which is when the function [`normalize`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/normalize.html) was first introduced. The `which` command is showing you a `normalize` method for `dfilt` class objects (from the Signal Processing Toolbox) that existed prior, which only accepts arguments of type `dfilt`.

Comment: I tried with uint8 and single, I get the same error

Comment: `uint8` and `single` are not `dfilt` objects, why would you expect them to work?